# How to use bitwise operator in ArcGIS desktop to extract required pixels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, modis

MODIS QA dataset gives quality flags in decimal numbers that are required to be converted into binary format to assess data quality.

For a 8-bit system of MOD15A5 image, the decimal values 16 and 97 correspond to `000 10 0 0 0` and `011 00 0 0 1`.

Here, the extreme right digits i.e., 1 and 0 shows the quality. Based on the right most value of converted binary form, how to convert the pixels' decimal values to 0 and 1.

I tried using `bitwise` operator of `spatial-analyst` in ArcGIS desktop, but ain't getting how to use the functionality.

Comment: What is the objetive of the task? You want to use/calculate only pixel with the quality 0 or 1? In this case it can be done by using a condition that checks if the numbers are even or uneven. If it is not divisible by 2 it is an uneven number. And uneven number in binary always has the 1 in the last digit.

Comment: @Matte Thanks for the life saving tips. It should absolutely work, I guess.